# Is there a good JavaScript based page demo library out there?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a JavaScript library that allows the user to view a live demonstration/presentation of a webpage.

What I'm envisioning would be putting some sort of "demo" button on a webpage. The button would kick off a JavaScript driven page demonstration that highlighted specific elements on the page, faded the other elements out, and displayed modal explanation boxes talking about the elements highlighted. There would be forward/backward buttons that allow you to advance through the demonstration.

Are there JavaScript libraries that will do this?

Comment: I'm literally asking for recommendations on a tool. My question is like unto "I have a nail that I need to drive into wood, how should I do it" the first person to say "With a hammer" wins. This question absolutely has an answer that can be supported by references and specific expertise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like Joyride? It's a jQuery plugin that creates a walk-thru of your live website.
http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

> Want to take users through a tour of your app? We've got the right tool. Joyride gives you everything you need to call out new features in your app or website.

Alternatives are:

http://www.walkme.com/

> WalkMe enables website owners and app developers to easily create multiple interactive on-screen Walk-Thru’s that help users to quickly and easily complete even the most complex tasks.

https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS

> Guiders are a user experience design pattern for introducing users to a web application.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Stack Overflow comes through for me again!

Comment: Another alternative: https://github.com/usablica/intro.js

Answer (score -2):

Virtually all JS libraries *can* do this, but you're going to have to write the code yourself. Your requirement is pretty specific, so I doubt there's anything pre-written that already does this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure I saw a library or framework out there that does something similar a few years back (co-worker recalls this too) I just can't remember what it was called and Google isn't helping me...

Comment: StackOverflow is really for asking code-related questions. It's not intended to be a recommendation engine.

Comment: Then it is missing the boat on a legitimate use case that it actually used to fill (See 5 of my top 10 answers in my profile as well as 5 of my top 10 questions).